# CKEDITOR adding a simple button should not be this difficult

Tags: ckeditor

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('Copyall', {
init: function(editor) {
    editor.addCommand('copy_all', {
        exec : function(editor){
            alert('Yay!');
        }
    });
    editor.ui.addButton('Copyall', {
        label: 'Copy All',
        command: 'copy_all',
        toolbar: 'basicstyles',
        icon: 'https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/5500999?v=2&s=16'
    });
}
});

CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [
{name: 'basicstyles', items : ['Copyall', 'Font', 'FontSize', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Strike']},
];
```

I have a simple menu for inline CKEDITOR elements. I merely need a button to do some js work.

https://jsfiddle.net/elb_/as1km50L/

Answer (score 0):

Gine an id to your editable area:

```
<div id="editor1" contenteditable="true">some text</div>
```

Then, use your id to add the command and the button without a plugin:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.addCommand('copy_all', {
     exec : function(editor) {
         alert('Yay!');
     }
});

CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.ui.addButton('Copyall', {
    label: 'Copy All',
    command: 'copy_all',
    toolbar: 'basicstyles',
    icon: 'https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/5500999?v=2&s=16'
});

CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [
{name: 'basicstyles', items : ['Copyall', 'Font', 'FontSize', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Strike']},
];
```

See this: https://jsfiddle.net/as1km50L/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
CKEDITOR.inlineAll();
for (var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName].addCommand('copy_all', {
        exec: function(edt) {
           alert('Yay!');
        }   
    });

    CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName].ui.addButton('Copyall', {
        label: 'Copy All',
        command: 'copy_all',
        toolbar: 'basicstyles',
        icon: 'https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/5500999?v=2&s=16'
    }); 
}

CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [ 
    {name: 'basicstyles', items : ['Copyall', 'Font', 'FontSize', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Strike']},
];
```

See that CKEDITOR.inlineAll() method above? Turns out that CKEDITOR instances are not available to customize unless that beauty is there. It's also interesting to note that without the inlineAll(), the CKEDITOR.instances will show as populated, but for some reason cannot be iterated.

Anyway, problem solved.